# Correct gzip encoding on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip

While transferring my files using "aws s3 sync", transferred files does not have right Content-type and Content-encoding. I am able to solve the types by tweaking `/etc/mime.types` however no idea how to set right encoding for ".gz" extension so zipped files are served as text apart from:

- changing types on s3  afterwards (seems like double-work to me)
- aws-cli using exclude / include with correct types 
  (this results in multiple commands)

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "so zipped files are served as text"?

Comment: Basically I have gziped text files which I want to be served as text when accesed in opposed to be offered to download.

Comment: Is your intention to serve them as Zip files to browsers that understand how to optimize transfer to reduce bandwidth requirements? This might help: [Serving gzipped files in Amazon S3 / CloudFront - Zanon](https://zanon.io/posts/serving-gzipped-files-in-amazon-s3-cloudfront)

Comment: Not exactly. Simply put. I upload file "logs.gz" and when I go to static page lets say "bucket-url/task-logs/logs.gz I can read the logs directly.

Comment: Does the zip file contain more than one file?

Comment: Nope. It is always just one text file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it,

> aws s3 sync /tmp/foo/ s3://bucket/ --recursive 
>       --exclude "*" --include "*.gz"  --content-type "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"

By default aws s3 sync command assumes the best matching content types. If you want to change the default behavior you need to handle them separately.

**Reference:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already counted with this as per my question but this will result in at least two commands but thanks anyway...